# What is 'Memory allocation' used for in C?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I always here people saying something about the use of memory and C being difficult because of this whole memory thing, and memory leaks blah. Ive tried googling 'Memory allocation - C' and all I find is tutorials and stuff. Please can someone explain the memory usage or allocation?

Please forgive me if this question is not constructive, but thanks anyways!

Comment: I suggest you google for the use of the *heap*, and the `malloc()` and `free()` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern programming languages automatically manage the memory used to store higher-level pieces of program data (structures, objects, etc., depending on the language). In contrast, C requires the programmer to **allocate** and **deallocate** memory manually when programming. This requires more work, but also enables higher performance (if one is meticulous).

A memory leak occurs when one allocates a block of memory (e.g. to a C **structure**) and fails to deallocate it (which means freeing the memory up for other uses). In this case, the memory is still allocated, but not being used. Overtime, memory leaks can reduce the amount of available memory, and cause problems in persistent programs.

Answer (score 2):

Quickly.
In the most of the recent languages, when you creates a new object or data structure, you have to first create a **location** for your obj/struct.
Then you have to ask the permission in your program to create an obj/struct to put at this location.

In C it's a bit more complicated: first it's not object oriented, so you only have structures.
So when you creates a location for your structure, you have to explain to the compiler that you want a precise type of data and his size in memory. 
You also don't have variable sized arrays, or your array size will be known before the compilation, or you have to do a dynamic allocation.

*Example:*
In JAVA:

```
int x = 3;
FooClass [] obj;
FooClass = new FooClass[x];
```

In C:

```
int x = 3;
FooStruct *str; // This is a pointer: you are dealing with the memory adress
str = malloc(x * sizeof(FooStruct)); 
/* You are allocating x = 3 FooStruct elements at the adress str.
You have now an array of 3 FooStruct */
```

And last thing, in a lot of recent languages you have *Garbage collector*, but in C when you don't want to use a dynamicly allocated element, you have to deallocate it.

And it could be dangerous if you are inexperienced, because with dealing with the adresses in the memory, you can do unallowed operations, as using memory adress external to your program (even if it's secured though).